# JQuery $.get method to simulate clicking the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome, craigslist

I keep getting a SyntaxError when I put `.each(function(i, el) { 
 $.get(el.href, function(body) {` on the console, please help thank you.

```
var emails = "";
    $(".txt").find("a.hdrlnk").map(function(i, el) { return el })
    .each(function(i, el) { 
      $.get(el.href, function(body) { 
        $.get( $(body).find("#replylink")[0].href, function(linkbody) {
              var email = $(linkbody).find('a[href^="mailto:"]')[0].innerText + ',`enter code here`';
              emails += email;
        })
      })
    })
    setTimeout(function() { `enter code here`
      console.log('emails: ' + emails);
    }, 5000)
```

Comment: What is that `SyntaxError` ?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: The given code does not have a syntax error, so either you have some invisible character that does not exist in your given code here. Or the error is somewhere else. The error shown in the console shows a line telling you where in your code the error occurs, so first make sure it is really in this portion of your code.

Comment: Ok will do thank you!